# Integrate WYSIWYG TinyMCE in Admin Custom Module and Contact Us / CMS Page

Tags: cms, wysiwyg, tinymce, contact-us

I followed [this blog](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/how-to-use-wysiwyg-editor-tinymce-in-custom-admin-magento-module/) to add WYSIWYG editor (TinyMCE) in my custom Admin Magento Module. I can see it in my backend, but the issue is when I click on `Insert Image`, `Insert Variable` or `Insert Widget`, it shows me JS error in my Error Console.

Could someone shed some light on how to integrate WYSIWYG in backend as well as on frontend (ex: Contact Us Page) with the correct Magento approach.

Thanks

Comment: What's the error in the console?

Comment: `Insert Widget: ReferenceError: widgetTools is not defined`
`Insert Image : MediabrowserUtility is not defined`
`Insert Variable: MagentovariablePlugin is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your page is missing the inclusion of the `widget.js` file. This is normally added in the admin section based on the layout handle `editor`.

```
<action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/widget.js</script></action>
```

I would suggest that for you custom page you also add the `editor` layout handle to include add the js and css required.

```
<your_customer_handle>
    <update handle="editor"/>
</your_customer_handle>
```